Вывод в цикле 3 через 3
Помогите вывести строки 3 через 3.
Здесь получается 3 через 1. Что делаю не так:
DECLARE @number INT
    ,@name1 VARCHAR(10) = 'Employee'
    ,@name2 VARCHAR(10) = 'Employee_2'
SET @number = 1

WHILE @number <= 50
BEGIN
    Print CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @name1)
    SET @number = @number + 1
    IF @number % 3 = 0
    SET @number = @number + 1
        ELSE 
        Print CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @name2)
        CONTINUE
END;



Какой вывод в результате Вы хотите получить? Пишете - по 3 сроки через 3, я наблюдаю 2 через 1, а не 3 через 1

Извиняюсь. Опечатался. Действительно 2 через 1 в результате.
Нужно 3 через 3
Спасибо

Ещё раз повторю вопрос - Какой вывод в результате Вы хотите получить?

Вывод: 3 записи - Employee, Затем 3 записи - Employee_2, затем снова 3 записи - Employee
И так пока не дойдет до 50 записей. Я откровенно говоря, не знаю как еще это объяснить. Три записи через. Сначала три таких, затем 3 других

Не уверен в синтаксисе, но алгоритм - такой:
WHILE @number <= 50
BEGIN
    SET @number = @number + 1
    IF @number % 6 < 3
        Print CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @name1)
    ELSE 
        Print CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @name2)
    ENDIF
END;


DECLARE @i INT = 0
DECLARE @repeat INT = 3 --кол-во повторений
DECLARE @name1 VARCHAR(10) = 'Employee_1'
DECLARE @name2 VARCHAR(10) = 'Employee_2'

WHILE @i <= 50
BEGIN
    
    IF @i % (@repeat * 2) < @repeat
        PRINT @name1
    ELSE
        PRINT @name2

    SET @i += 1

END

